# Combobox select only with Enter

Tags: c#, combobox

Currently I am using a custom combobox with "SelectedIndexChange" to perform some actions when the user selects an Item from the combobox. The issue is, I cannot use the arrow keys to go through the list of items and press enter to select. When i open the list, if i use the arrow keys, it selects the first highlighted item on the list. I want the user to be able to scroll through the list with the arrow keys and use enter/tab to select.

Comment: When your focus is on combo box, press `Alt+DownArow` key, this will expand the drop down, Then press `Enter` to select the desired item. It should work, and a standard way of doing it with dropdown lists.

Comment: @Yogi sorry this doesn't help; what i am trying to say is, for example if i have  a list of null,1,2,3,4,5. If i click or Alt DownArrow to open the combobox , I cant cycle through the list with arrow keys. The next selection with arrow keys gets taken always